# Why doesn't Mathematica simplify this root

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am puzzled by the following results Mathematica gives me. I am using Mathematica 11.3 on Linux:

If I evaluate

`In[1]:=Assuming[x + y + z + v*w > 0, FullSimplify[Sqrt[(x + y + z + v*w)^2]]]
Out[1]:=Abs[v w + x + y + z]`

However, if I evaluate

`In[2]:=Assuming[x + y + z + v > 0, FullSimplify[Sqrt[(x + y + z + v)^2]]]
Out[2]:=v + x + y + z`

Can somebody tell me why the first Output is still encapsulated by the absolute value? Is this the same in other versions of Mathematica?

Comment: `Simplify[Sqrt[(x+y+z+v*w)^2],x+y+z+v*w==q&&q>0]/.q->x+y+z+v*w` returns `v*w+x+y+z`

Comment: That helps, but why doesn't Mathematica do the simplification in the first case? Is the expression with 4 terms where one is a product already too complicated?

Comment: No one, at least outside Wolfram, really knows the exact details of the algorithm that something as complicated as `FullSimplify` uses. It is all guesswork to some degree.